# Read Nested XML in C# with no XSLT file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, delimited

I have an XML file with 3-4 levels deep of nested children.  Some of the children have either a missing element or an extra element.  I am struggling with automating reading the xml x children deep and also creating the appropriate flat delimited records to match the parent item.  I am using VS 2015 and C# in a winform application and the end result of the file is that they record structure needs to be the same for all the items regardless of any missing or blank elements.  Below is my button click event along with a sampling of the data I am dealing with.  Note ITEM 1 has 1 Zoning Node, ITEM 2 has 2 Zoning Nodes and ITEM 3 has 0 Zoning Nodes.  The result throws off my column Counts in the delimited file for when I bring it into EXCEL for example.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string sDelimiter = "";
            string sNodeName = "";
            string sChildNodeName = "";
            switch (uicmbDelimiter.Text)
            {
                case "TAB":
                    sDelimiter = "\t";
                    break;
                case "PIPE":
                    sDelimiter = "|";
                    break;
                case "COMMA":
                    sDelimiter = ",";
                    break;
                default:
                    sDelimiter = ",";
                    break;
            }

            string csvstring = "";
            StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(this.uitxtXMLFile.Text + ".out");

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(this.uitxtXMLFile.Text);
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "http://www.revenue.wi.gov/slf");
            XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("//ab:Item", nsmgr);
            foreach (XmlNode xnfields in nodelist)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode childnode in xnfields.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (childnode.ChildNodes.Count > 1)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode children in childnode.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            csvstring +=children.LocalName + sDelimiter;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        csvstring += childnode.LocalName + sDelimiter;
                    }
                }
                csv.WriteLine(csvstring);
                csvstring = "";
                break;
            }
            csvstring = "";

            foreach (XmlNode xn in nodelist)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode childnode in xn.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (childnode.ChildNodes.Count > 1)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode children in childnode.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            if ((sChildNodeName != children.LocalName) && sChildNodeName !="" )
                            {
                                csvstring += sDelimiter + children.InnerText;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                csvstring += children.InnerText;
                            }
                            sChildNodeName = children.LocalName;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        csvstring += childnode.InnerText;
                    }
                    ///////////
                    ///
                    ///////////
                    if ((sNodeName != childnode.LocalName))
                    {
                        csvstring += sDelimiter;
                    }
                    sNodeName = childnode.LocalName;
                }
                csv.WriteLine(csvstring);
                csvstring = "";
                sNodeName = "";
                sChildNodeName = "";
            }

            csv.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);

        }


    }
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CountyRolls xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.revenue.wi.gov/slf">
  <Municipality>
    <MunicipalityNumber>002</MunicipalityNumber>
    <Item>
      <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
      <PropertyInfo>
        <LocalID1>1-00001-000</LocalID1>
        <LocalID2>1</LocalID2>
        <Zoning>EXCLUSIVE AGRICULTURE DISTRICT</Zoning>
        <Town>16</Town>
        <Range>05</Range>
        <RangeDirection>W</RangeDirection>
        <Section>01</Section>
        <Quarter40>NE</Quarter40>
        <Quarter160>NE</Quarter160>
        <Legal>FRAC NE1/4 OF NE1/4</Legal>
        <RecordingDocuments>
          <Book>0</Book>
          <Page>0</Page>
          <DocumentNumber>1569517</DocumentNumber>
        </RecordingDocuments>
        <RecordingDocuments>
          <Book>589</Book>
          <Page>204</Page>
          <DocumentNumber>868152</DocumentNumber>
        </RecordingDocuments>
      </PropertyInfo>
      <OwnerAndAddressInfo>
        <MailingAddress>
          <USAddress>
            <AddressLine1>N4929 COUNTY ROAD J</AddressLine1>
            <City>ROCKLAND</City>
            <State>WI</State>
            <ZIPCode>54653</ZIPCode>
          </USAddress>
        </MailingAddress>
        <Owner>
          <Individual>
            <Name>
              <FirstName>DAVID</FirstName>
              <LastName>AXELSEN IRREVOCABLE LIVING TRUST</LastName>
            </Name>
            <Address>
              <USAddress>
                <AddressLine1>N4929 COUNTY ROAD J</AddressLine1>
                <City>ROCKLAND</City>
                <State>WI</State>
                <ZIPCode>54653</ZIPCode>
              </USAddress>
            </Address>
          </Individual>
        </Owner>
        <Owner>
          <Individual>
            <Name>
              <FirstName>RHEA</FirstName>
              <LastName>AXELSEN IRREVOCABLE LIVING TRUST</LastName>
            </Name>
            <Address>
              <USAddress>
                <AddressLine1>N4929 COUNTY ROAD J</AddressLine1>
                <City>ROCKLAND</City>
                <State>WI</State>
                <ZIPCode>54653</ZIPCode>
              </USAddress>
            </Address>
          </Individual>
        </Owner>
        <SiteAddress>
          <AddressLine1>JACKPOT AVE</AddressLine1>
          <City>ROCKLAND</City>
          <State>WI</State>
          <ZIPCode>54653</ZIPCode>
        </SiteAddress>
      </OwnerAndAddressInfo>
      <ValuationInfo>
        <RealProperty>
          <Class4>
            <Acres>8.000</Acres>
            <LandValue>1200</LandValue>
            <ImprovementsValue>0</ImprovementsValue>
          </Class4>
          <Class5M>
            <Acres>31.460</Acres>
            <LandValue>50300</LandValue>
            <ImprovementsValue>0</ImprovementsValue>
          </Class5M>
          <ClassTotal>
            <Acres>39.460</Acres>
            <LandValue>51500</LandValue>
            <ImprovementsValue>0</ImprovementsValue>
          </ClassTotal>
        </RealProperty>
      </ValuationInfo>
      <JurisdictionInfo>
        <County>
          <CountyName>32 La Crosse</CountyName>
          <CountyRate>0.004068228</CountyRate>
          <CountyTax>209.51</CountyTax>
        </County>
        <Municipality>
          <MuniName>Town of Bangor</MuniName>
          <MuniNumber>32002</MuniNumber>
          <MunicipalRate>0.002443039</MunicipalRate>
          <MunicipalTax>125.82</MunicipalTax>
        </Municipality>
        <School>
          <Code>320245</Code>
          <Rate>0.009154910</Rate>
          <Tax>471.48</Tax>
        </School>
        <Tech>
          <Code>000200</Code>
          <Rate>0.001590738</Rate>
          <Tax>81.92</Tax>
        </Tech>
      </JurisdictionInfo>
      <TaxSummary>
        <LandTaxableTotal>51500</LandTaxableTotal>
        <ImprovementsTaxableTotal>0</ImprovementsTaxableTotal>
        <TotalTaxableValue>51500</TotalTaxableValue>
        <EstimatedFairMarketValue>0</EstimatedFairMarketValue>
        <StateTax>8.86</StateTax>
        <OccupationalTax>0</OccupationalTax>
        <ForestTaxable>0</ForestTaxable>
        <BORValue>51500</BORValue>
        <PrivateForestCropTax>0.00</PrivateForestCropTax>
        <ManagedForestLawTax>0.00</ManagedForestLawTax>
        <TaxTotal>897.59</TaxTotal>
        <SchoolCredit>95.43</SchoolCredit>
        <LotteryCredit>0.00</LotteryCredit>
        <FirstDollarCredit>0.00</FirstDollarCredit>
        <SpecialAssessment>
          <SpecialAssessmentDesc>No special charge applies to parcel.</SpecialAssessmentDesc>
          <SpecialAssessmentCharge>0</SpecialAssessmentCharge>
        </SpecialAssessment>
        <DelinquentUtilityCharges>0</DelinquentUtilityCharges>
        <NetTax>897.59</NetTax>
        <Payment>0</Payment>
        <AmountDue>897.59</AmountDue>
        <PriorYearChargebacks>
          <Total>0</Total>
        </PriorYearChargebacks>
        <StateAssessedTelco>0</StateAssessedTelco>
      </TaxSummary>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <RecordNumber>2</RecordNumber>
      <PropertyInfo>
        <LocalID1>1-00003-001</LocalID1>
        <LocalID2>4</LocalID2>
        <Zoning>CONDITIONAL ZONING            </Zoning>
        <Zoning>EXCLUSIVE AGRICULTURE DISTRICT</Zoning>
        <Town>16</Town>
        <Range>05</Range>
        <RangeDirection>W</RangeDirection>
        <Section>01</Section>
        <Quarter40>NE</Quarter40>
        <Quarter160>SW</Quarter160>
        <Legal>CERTIFIED SURVEY MAP NO. 64 VOL 7 LOT 1 DOC NO. 1159544</Legal>
        <RecordingDocuments>
          <Book>7</Book>
          <Page>64</Page>
          <DocumentNumber>1159544</DocumentNumber>
        </RecordingDocuments>
        <RecordingDocuments>
          <Book>872</Book>
          <Page>36</Page>
          <DocumentNumber>1039008</DocumentNumber>
        </RecordingDocuments>
        <RecordingDocuments>
          <Book>1129</Book>
          <Page>264</Page>
          <DocumentNumber>1152228</DocumentNumber>
        </RecordingDocuments>
        <RecordingDocuments>
          <Book>1140</Book>
          <Page>558</Page>
          <DocumentNumber>1156940</DocumentNumber>
        </RecordingDocuments>
        <RecordingDocuments>
          <Book>1156</Book>
          <Page>31</Page>
          <DocumentNumber>1163596</DocumentNumber>
        </RecordingDocuments>
      </PropertyInfo>
      <OwnerAndAddressInfo>
        <MailingAddress>
          <USAddress>
            <AddressLine1>N4746 COUNTY ROAD J</AddressLine1>
            <City>ROCKLAND</City>
            <State>WI</State>
            <ZIPCode>54653</ZIPCode>
          </USAddress>
        </MailingAddress>
        <Owner>
          <Individual>
            <Name>
              <FirstName>SCOTT R</FirstName>
              <LastName>MILDE</LastName>
            </Name>
            <Address>
              <USAddress>
                <AddressLine1>N4746 COUNTY ROAD J</AddressLine1>
                <City>ROCKLAND</City>
                <State>WI</State>
                <ZIPCode>54653</ZIPCode>
              </USAddress>
            </Address>
          </Individual>
        </Owner>
        <Owner>
          <Individual>
            <Name>
              <FirstName>SUSAN T</FirstName>
              <LastName>MILDE</LastName>
            </Name>
          </Individual>
        </Owner>
        <SiteAddress>
          <AddressLine1>N4746 COUNTY ROAD J</AddressLine1>
          <City>ROCKLAND</City>
          <State>WI</State>
          <ZIPCode>54653</ZIPCode>
        </SiteAddress>
      </OwnerAndAddressInfo>
      <ValuationInfo>
        <RealProperty>
          <Class1>
            <Acres>1.760</Acres>
            <LandValue>13800</LandValue>
            <ImprovementsValue>127400</ImprovementsValue>
          </Class1>
          <ClassTotal>
            <Acres>1.760</Acres>
            <LandValue>13800</LandValue>
            <ImprovementsValue>127400</ImprovementsValue>
          </ClassTotal>
        </RealProperty>
      </ValuationInfo>
      <JurisdictionInfo>
        <County>
          <CountyName>32 La Crosse</CountyName>
          <CountyRate>0.004068228</CountyRate>
          <CountyTax>574.43</CountyTax>
        </County>
        <Municipality>
          <MuniName>Town of Bangor</MuniName>
          <MuniNumber>32002</MuniNumber>
          <MunicipalRate>0.002443039</MunicipalRate>
          <MunicipalTax>344.96</MunicipalTax>
        </Municipality>
        <School>
          <Code>320245</Code>
          <Rate>0.009154910</Rate>
          <Tax>1292.67</Tax>
        </School>
        <Tech>
          <Code>000200</Code>
          <Rate>0.001590738</Rate>
          <Tax>224.61</Tax>
        </Tech>
      </JurisdictionInfo>
      <TaxSummary>
        <LandTaxableTotal>13800</LandTaxableTotal>
        <ImprovementsTaxableTotal>127400</ImprovementsTaxableTotal>
        <TotalTaxableValue>141200</TotalTaxableValue>
        <EstimatedFairMarketValue>143200</EstimatedFairMarketValue>
        <StateTax>24.30</StateTax>
        <OccupationalTax>0</OccupationalTax>
        <ForestTaxable>0</ForestTaxable>
        <BORValue>141200</BORValue>
        <PrivateForestCropTax>0.00</PrivateForestCropTax>
        <ManagedForestLawTax>0.00</ManagedForestLawTax>
        <TaxTotal>2460.97</TaxTotal>
        <SchoolCredit>261.64</SchoolCredit>
        <LotteryCredit>136.65</LotteryCredit>
        <FirstDollarCredit>72.66</FirstDollarCredit>
        <SpecialAssessment>
          <SpecialAssessmentDesc>No special charge applies to parcel.</SpecialAssessmentDesc>
          <SpecialAssessmentCharge>0</SpecialAssessmentCharge>
        </SpecialAssessment>
        <DelinquentUtilityCharges>0</DelinquentUtilityCharges>
        <NetTax>2251.66</NetTax>
        <Payment>0</Payment>
        <AmountDue>2251.66</AmountDue>
        <PriorYearChargebacks>
          <Total>0</Total>
        </PriorYearChargebacks>
        <StateAssessedTelco>0</StateAssessedTelco>
      </TaxSummary>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <RecordNumber>3</RecordNumber>
      <PropertyInfo>
        <LocalID1>1-00004-000</LocalID1>
        <LocalID2>5</LocalID2>
        <Town>16</Town>
        <Range>05</Range>
        <RangeDirection>W</RangeDirection>
        <Section>01</Section>
        <Quarter40>NE</Quarter40>
        <Quarter160>SE</Quarter160>
        <Legal>SE1/4 FRAC NE1/4</Legal>
        <RecordingDocuments>
          <Book>870</Book>
          <Page>575</Page>
          <DocumentNumber>1038082</DocumentNumber>
        </RecordingDocuments>
        <RecordingDocuments>
          <Book>872</Book>
          <Page>36</Page>
          <DocumentNumber>1039008</DocumentNumber>
        </RecordingDocuments>
        <RecordingDocuments>
          <Book>1129</Book>
          <Page>264</Page>
          <DocumentNumber>1152228</DocumentNumber>
        </RecordingDocuments>
        <RecordingDocuments>
          <Book>1140</Book>
          <Page>558</Page>
          <DocumentNumber>1156940</DocumentNumber>
        </RecordingDocuments>
        <RecordingDocuments>
          <Book>1336</Book>
          <Page>55</Page>
          <DocumentNumber>1234542</DocumentNumber>
        </RecordingDocuments>
        <RecordingDocuments>
          <Book>1336</Book>
          <Page>523</Page>
          <DocumentNumber>1234736</DocumentNumber>
        </RecordingDocuments>
        <RecordingDocuments>
          <Book>1385</Book>
          <Page>535</Page>
          <DocumentNumber>1254119</DocumentNumber>
        </RecordingDocuments>
      </PropertyInfo>
      <OwnerAndAddressInfo>
        <MailingAddress>
          <USAddress>
            <AddressLine1>230 21ST ST S</AddressLine1>
            <City>LA CROSSE</City>
            <State>WI</State>
            <ZIPCode>54601</ZIPCode>
          </USAddress>
        </MailingAddress>
        <Owner>
          <Individual>
            <Name>
              <FirstName>GALEN W</FirstName>
              <LastName>PITTMAN</LastName>
            </Name>
            <Address>
              <USAddress>
                <AddressLine1>230 21ST ST S</AddressLine1>
                <City>LA CROSSE</City>
                <State>WI</State>
                <ZIPCode>54601</ZIPCode>
              </USAddress>
            </Address>
          </Individual>
        </Owner>
        <SiteAddress>
          <AddressLine1>COUNTY ROAD J</AddressLine1>
          <City>ROCKLAND</City>
          <State>WI</State>
          <ZIPCode>54653</ZIPCode>
        </SiteAddress>
      </OwnerAndAddressInfo>
      <ValuationInfo>
        <RealProperty>
          <Class5>
            <Acres>9.000</Acres>
            <LandValue>11700</LandValue>
            <ImprovementsValue>0</ImprovementsValue>
          </Class5>
          <Class6>
            <Acres>31.000</Acres>
            <LandValue>99200</LandValue>
            <ImprovementsValue>0</ImprovementsValue>
          </Class6>
          <ClassTotal>
            <Acres>40.000</Acres>
            <LandValue>110900</LandValue>
            <ImprovementsValue>0</ImprovementsValue>
          </ClassTotal>
        </RealProperty>
      </ValuationInfo>
      <JurisdictionInfo>
        <County>
          <CountyName>32 La Crosse</CountyName>
          <CountyRate>0.004068228</CountyRate>
          <CountyTax>451.17</CountyTax>
        </County>
        <Municipality>
          <MuniName>Town of Bangor</MuniName>
          <MuniNumber>32002</MuniNumber>
          <MunicipalRate>0.002443039</MunicipalRate>
          <MunicipalTax>270.93</MunicipalTax>
        </Municipality>
        <School>
          <Code>320245</Code>
          <Rate>0.009154910</Rate>
          <Tax>1015.28</Tax>
        </School>
        <Tech>
          <Code>000200</Code>
          <Rate>0.001590738</Rate>
          <Tax>176.41</Tax>
        </Tech>
      </JurisdictionInfo>
      <TaxSummary>
        <LandTaxableTotal>110900</LandTaxableTotal>
        <ImprovementsTaxableTotal>0</ImprovementsTaxableTotal>
        <TotalTaxableValue>110900</TotalTaxableValue>
        <EstimatedFairMarketValue>112500</EstimatedFairMarketValue>
        <StateTax>19.09</StateTax>
        <OccupationalTax>0</OccupationalTax>
        <ForestTaxable>0</ForestTaxable>
        <BORValue>110900</BORValue>
        <PrivateForestCropTax>0.00</PrivateForestCropTax>
        <ManagedForestLawTax>0.00</ManagedForestLawTax>
        <TaxTotal>1932.88</TaxTotal>
        <SchoolCredit>205.50</SchoolCredit>
        <LotteryCredit>0.00</LotteryCredit>
        <FirstDollarCredit>0.00</FirstDollarCredit>
        <SpecialAssessment>
          <SpecialAssessmentDesc>No special charge applies to parcel.</SpecialAssessmentDesc>
          <SpecialAssessmentCharge>0</SpecialAssessmentCharge>
        </SpecialAssessment>
        <DelinquentUtilityCharges>0</DelinquentUtilityCharges>
        <NetTax>1932.88</NetTax>
        <Payment>0</Payment>
        <AmountDue>1932.88</AmountDue>
        <PriorYearChargebacks>
          <Total>0</Total>
        </PriorYearChargebacks>
        <StateAssessedTelco>0</StateAssessedTelco>
      </TaxSummary>
    </Item>
    <Chargebacks>
      <CurrentYear>
        <Total>0</Total>
      </CurrentYear>
    </Chargebacks>
  </Municipality>
</CountyRolls>
```

Comment: I would copy the xml to the clipboard and use VS "paste xml as classes" feature. Then implement a method in that class that writes it out as delimitted string. Then you can just use XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xml linq handles null values better.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement countyRolls = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ns = countyRolls.GetDefaultNamespace();

            var results = countyRolls.Elements(ns + "Municipality").Select(x => new {
                municipalityNumber = (string)x.Element(ns + "MunicipalityNumber"),
                items = x.Elements(ns + "Item").Select(y => new {
                   recordNumber = (int)y.Element(ns + "RecordNumber"),
                   propertyInfo = y.Elements(ns + "PropertyInfo").Select(z => new {
                      localID1 = (string)z.Element(ns + "LocalID1"),
                      localID2 = (string)z.Element(ns + "LocalID2"),
                      zoning = z.Elements(ns + "Zoning").Select(a => (string)a).ToArray(),
                      town = (string)z.Element(ns + "Town"),
                      range = (string)z.Element(ns + "Range"),
                      rangeDirection = (string)z.Element(ns + "RangeDirection"),
                      section = (string)z.Element(ns + "Section"),
                      quarter40 = (string)z.Element(ns + "Quarter40"),
                      quarter160 = (string)z.Element(ns + "Quarter160"),
                      legal = (string)z.Element(ns + "Legal"),
                      recordingDocuments = z.Elements(ns + "RecordingDocuments").Select(a => new {
                           book = (int)a.Element(ns + "Book"),
                           page = (int)a.Element(ns + "Page"),
                           documentNumber = (int)a.Element(ns + "DocumentNumber")
                      }).ToList()
                   }).FirstOrDefault(),
                   ownerAndAddressInfo = y.Elements(ns + "OwnerAndAddressInfo").Select(z => new { 
                       mailingAddress = z.Descendants(ns + "USAddress").Select(a => new {
                           addressLine1 = (string)a.Element(ns + "AddressLine1"),
                           city = (string)a.Element(ns + "City"),
                           state = (string)a.Element(ns + "State"),
                           zipCode = (string)a.Element(ns + "ZIPCode"),
                       }).FirstOrDefault(),
                       owners = z.Elements(ns + "Owner").Select(a => new {
                           firstName = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "FirstName").FirstOrDefault(),
                           lastName = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "LastName").FirstOrDefault(),
                           addressLine1 = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "AddressLine1").FirstOrDefault(),
                           city = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "City").FirstOrDefault(),
                           state = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "State").FirstOrDefault(),
                           zipCode = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "ZIPCode").FirstOrDefault(),
                       }).ToList(),
                       siteAddress = z.Elements(ns + "SiteAddress").Select(a => new {
                           addressLine1 = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "AddressLine1").FirstOrDefault(),
                           city = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "City").FirstOrDefault(),
                           state = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "State").FirstOrDefault(),
                           zipCode = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "ZIPCode").FirstOrDefault(),
                       }).FirstOrDefault()
                   }).FirstOrDefault(),
                   realProperty = y.Descendants(ns + "RealProperty").Select(z => new {
                       class4 = z.Elements(ns + "Class4").Select(a => new {
                          acres = (decimal)a.Element(ns + "Acres"),
                          landValue = (int)a.Element(ns + "LandValue"),
                          improvementsValue = (int)a.Element(ns + "ImprovementsValue")
                       }).FirstOrDefault(),
                       class5m = z.Elements(ns + "Class5M").Select(a => new {
                          acres = (decimal)a.Element(ns + "Acres"),
                          landValue = (int)a.Element(ns + "LandValue"),
                          improvementsValue = (int)a.Element(ns + "ImprovementsValue")
                       }).FirstOrDefault(),
                       classTotal = z.Elements(ns + "ClassTotal").Select(a => new {
                          acres = (decimal)a.Element(ns + "Acres"),
                          landValue = (int)a.Element(ns + "LandValue"),
                          improvementsValue = (int)a.Element(ns + "ImprovementsValue")
                       }).FirstOrDefault(),
                   }).FirstOrDefault(),
                   jurisdictionInfo = y.Elements(ns + "JurisdictionInfo").Select(z => new {
                       county = z.Elements(ns + "County").Select(a => new {
                           countName = (string)a.Element(ns + "CountyName"),
                           countRate = (string)a.Element(ns + "CountyRate"),
                           countTax = (string)a.Element(ns + "CountyTax")
                       }).FirstOrDefault(),
                       municipality = z.Elements(ns + "Municipality").Select(a => new {
                           muniName = (string)a.Element(ns + "MuniName"),
                           muniNumber = (string)a.Element(ns + "MuniNumber"),
                           municipalRate = (string)a.Element(ns + "MunicipalRate"),
                           municipalTax = (string)a.Element(ns + "MunicipalTax")
                       }).FirstOrDefault(),
                       school = z.Elements(ns + "School").Select(a => new {
                           code = (string)a.Element(ns + "Code"),
                           rate = (string)a.Element(ns + "Rate"),
                           tax = (string)a.Element(ns + "Tax")
                       }).FirstOrDefault(),
                       tech = z.Elements(ns + "Tech").Select(a => new {
                           code = (string)a.Element(ns + "Code"),
                           rate = (string)a.Element(ns + "Rate"),
                           tax = (string)a.Element(ns + "Tax")
                       }).FirstOrDefault()
                   }).FirstOrDefault(),
                   taxSummary = y.Elements(ns + "TaxSummary").Select(z => new {
                       landTaxableTotal = (int)z.Element(ns + "LandTaxableTotal"),
                       improvementsTaxableTotal = (int)z.Element(ns + "ImprovementsTaxableTotal"),
                       totalTaxableValue = (int)z.Element(ns + "TotalTaxableValue"),
                       estimatedFairMarketValue = (int)z.Element(ns + "EstimatedFairMarketValue"),
                       stateTax = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "StateTax"),
                       occupationalTax = (int)z.Element(ns + "OccupationalTax"),
                       forestTaxable = (int)z.Element(ns + "ForestTaxable"),
                       bORValue = (int)z.Element(ns + "BORValue"),
                       privateForestCropTax = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "PrivateForestCropTax"),
                       managedForestLawTax = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "ManagedForestLawTax"),
                       taxTotal = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "TaxTotal"),
                       schoolCredit = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "SchoolCredit"),
                       lotteryCredit = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "LotteryCredit"),
                       firstDollarCredit = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "FirstDollarCredit"),
                       specialAssessmentDesc = (string)z.Descendants(ns + "SpecialAssessmentDesc").FirstOrDefault(),
                       specialAssessmentCharge = (decimal)z.Descendants(ns + "SpecialAssessmentCharge").FirstOrDefault(),
                       delinquentUtilityCharges = (int)z.Element(ns + "DelinquentUtilityCharges"),
                       netTax= (decimal)z.Element(ns + "NetTax"),
                       payment = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "Payment"),
                       amountDue = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "AmountDue")
                   }).FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToList(),
                chargebacks = x.Element(ns + "Chargebacks").Descendants(ns + "Total").Select(y => y == null ? 0 : (int)y).FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks jdweng!  That helped immensely!!  I had to make a minor trweak to the SpecialAssessmentCharge field to decimal from int but it parsed my first file correctly.  The only drawback I see is there are records that have multiple ZONING elements in the

Comment: I changed zoning in posted code as follows : zoning = z.Elements(ns + "Zoning").Select(a => (string)a).ToArray(),  It could be either ToArray() or ToList() whichever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks again.. That is exactly what I needed there as well and works perfectly as you have defined it.  This is an excellent example of interpreting the XML files that I will be receiving and a good study for future files!  Well done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample of the completed working code:

```
    private void uicmdLocate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog myFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        myFile.Title = "Locate XML File";
        myFile.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
        if (myFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.uitxtXMLFile.Text = myFile.FileName;
        }

    }


    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            if (this.uitxtXMLFile.Text == "")
            {
                throw new Exception("You must select an XML file to convert!");
            }
            string sDelimeter = "";
            string sExtension = "";
            switch (uicmbDelimiter.Text)
            {
                case "TAB":
                    sDelimeter = "\t";
                    sExtension = ".txt";
                    break;
                case "PIPE":
                    sDelimeter = "|";
                    sExtension = ".txt";
                    break;
                case "COMMA":
                    sDelimeter = ",";
                    sExtension = ".csv";
                    break;
                default:
                    sDelimeter = "\t";
                    sExtension = ".txt";
                    break;
            }

            StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(this.uitxtXMLFile.Text.Replace(".xml",sExtension));
            string csvstring = "";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(this.uitxtXMLFile.Text);
            XElement countyRolls = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ns = countyRolls.GetDefaultNamespace();

            var results = countyRolls.Elements(ns + "Municipality").Select(x => new {
                municipalityNumber = (string)x.Element(ns + "MunicipalityNumber"),
                items = x.Elements(ns + "Item").Select(y => new {
                    recordNumber = (int)y.Element(ns + "RecordNumber"),
                    propertyInfo = y.Elements(ns + "PropertyInfo").Select(z => new {
                        localID1 = (string)z.Element(ns + "LocalID1"),
                        localID2 = (string)z.Element(ns + "LocalID2"),
                        zoning = z.Elements(ns + "Zoning").Select(a => (string)a).ToArray(),
                        town = (string)z.Element(ns + "Town"),
                        range = (string)z.Element(ns + "Range"),
                        rangeDirection = (string)z.Element(ns + "RangeDirection"),
                        section = (string)z.Element(ns + "Section"),
                        quarter40 = (string)z.Element(ns + "Quarter40"),
                        quarter160 = (string)z.Element(ns + "Quarter160"),
                        legal = (string)z.Element(ns + "Legal"),
                        recordingDocuments = z.Elements(ns + "RecordingDocuments").Select(a => new {
                            book = (int)a.Element(ns + "Book"),
                            page = (int)a.Element(ns + "Page"),
                            documentNumber = (int)a.Element(ns + "DocumentNumber")
                        }).ToList()
                    }).FirstOrDefault(),
                    ownerAndAddressInfo = y.Elements(ns + "OwnerAndAddressInfo").Select(z => new {
                        mailingAddress = z.Descendants(ns + "USAddress").Select(a => new {
                            addressLine1 = (string)a.Element(ns + "AddressLine1"),
                            city = (string)a.Element(ns + "City"),
                            state = (string)a.Element(ns + "State"),
                            zipCode = (string)a.Element(ns + "ZIPCode"),
                        }).FirstOrDefault(),
                        owners = z.Elements(ns + "Owner").Select(a => new {
                            firstName = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "FirstName").FirstOrDefault(),
                            lastName = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "LastName").FirstOrDefault(),
                            businessNameLine1 = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "BusinessNameLine1").FirstOrDefault(),
                            addressLine1 = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "AddressLine1").FirstOrDefault(),
                            city = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "City").FirstOrDefault(),
                            state = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "State").FirstOrDefault(),
                            zipCode = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "ZIPCode").FirstOrDefault(),
                        }).ToList(),
                        siteAddress = z.Elements(ns + "SiteAddress").Select(a => new {
                            addressLine1 = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "AddressLine1").FirstOrDefault(),
                            city = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "City").FirstOrDefault(),
                            state = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "State").FirstOrDefault(),
                            zipCode = (string)a.Descendants(ns + "ZIPCode").FirstOrDefault(),
                        }).FirstOrDefault()
                    }).FirstOrDefault(),
                    realProperty = y.Descendants(ns + "RealProperty").Select(z => new {
                        class4 = z.Elements(ns + "Class4").Select(a => new {
                            acres = (decimal)a.Element(ns + "Acres"),
                            landValue = (int)a.Element(ns + "LandValue"),
                            improvementsValue = (int)a.Element(ns + "ImprovementsValue")
                        }).FirstOrDefault(),
                        class5m = z.Elements(ns + "Class5M").Select(a => new {
                            acres = (decimal)a.Element(ns + "Acres"),
                            landValue = (int)a.Element(ns + "LandValue"),
                            improvementsValue = (int)a.Element(ns + "ImprovementsValue")
                        }).FirstOrDefault(),
                        classTotal = z.Elements(ns + "ClassTotal").Select(a => new {
                            acres = (decimal)a.Element(ns + "Acres"),
                            landValue = (int)a.Element(ns + "LandValue"),
                            improvementsValue = (int)a.Element(ns + "ImprovementsValue")
                        }).FirstOrDefault(),
                    }).FirstOrDefault(),
                    jurisdictionInfo = y.Elements(ns + "JurisdictionInfo").Select(z => new {
                        county = z.Elements(ns + "County").Select(a => new {
                            countName = (string)a.Element(ns + "CountyName"),
                            countRate = (string)a.Element(ns + "CountyRate"),
                            countTax = (string)a.Element(ns + "CountyTax")
                        }).FirstOrDefault(),
                        municipality = z.Elements(ns + "Municipality").Select(a => new {
                            muniName = (string)a.Element(ns + "MuniName"),
                            muniNumber = (string)a.Element(ns + "MuniNumber"),
                            municipalRate = (string)a.Element(ns + "MunicipalRate"),
                            municipalTax = (string)a.Element(ns + "MunicipalTax")
                        }).FirstOrDefault(),
                        school = z.Elements(ns + "School").Select(a => new {
                            code = (string)a.Element(ns + "Code"),
                            rate = (string)a.Element(ns + "Rate"),
                            tax = (string)a.Element(ns + "Tax")
                        }).FirstOrDefault(),
                        tech = z.Elements(ns + "Tech").Select(a => new {
                            code = (string)a.Element(ns + "Code"),
                            rate = (string)a.Element(ns + "Rate"),
                            tax = (string)a.Element(ns + "Tax")
                        }).FirstOrDefault()
                    }).FirstOrDefault(),
                    taxSummary = y.Elements(ns + "TaxSummary").Select(z => new
                    {
                        landTaxableTotal = (int)z.Element(ns + "LandTaxableTotal"),
                        improvementsTaxableTotal = (int)z.Element(ns + "ImprovementsTaxableTotal"),
                        totalTaxableValue = (int)z.Element(ns + "TotalTaxableValue"),
                        estimatedFairMarketValue = (int)z.Element(ns + "EstimatedFairMarketValue"),
                        stateTax = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "StateTax"),
                        occupationalTax = (int)z.Element(ns + "OccupationalTax"),
                        forestTaxable = (int)z.Element(ns + "ForestTaxable"),
                        bORValue = (int)z.Element(ns + "BORValue"),
                        privateForestCropTax = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "PrivateForestCropTax"),
                        managedForestLawTax = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "ManagedForestLawTax"),
                        taxTotal = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "TaxTotal"),
                        schoolCredit = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "SchoolCredit"),
                        lotteryCredit = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "LotteryCredit"),
                        firstDollarCredit = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "FirstDollarCredit"),
                        specialAssessmentDesc = (string)z.Descendants(ns + "SpecialAssessmentDesc").FirstOrDefault(),
                        specialAssessmentCharge = (decimal)z.Descendants(ns + "SpecialAssessmentCharge").FirstOrDefault(),
                        delinquentUtilityCharges = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "DelinquentUtilityCharges"),
                        netTax = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "NetTax"),
                        payment = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "Payment"),
                        amountDue = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "AmountDue"),
                        priorYearChargebacks = (decimal)z.Descendants(ns + "Total").FirstOrDefault(),
                        stateAssessedTelco = (decimal)z.Element(ns + "StateAssessedTelco")
                    }).FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToList(),
                chargebacks = x.Element(ns + "Chargebacks").Descendants(ns + "Total").Select(y => y == null ? 0 : (int)y).FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();

            this.progressBar1.Maximum = results[0].items.Count;
            this.progressBar1.Value = 0;
            this.progressBar1.Step = 1;

            csvstring += "recordNumber" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "localID1" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "localID2" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "legal" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "addressLine1" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "city" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "state" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "zipCode" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "owner" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "NameSeq" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "BusinessName" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "siteaddressLine1" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "sitecity" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "sitestate" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "sitezipCode" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "acres" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "landValue" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "improvementsValue" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "landTaxableTotal" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "improvementsTaxableTotal" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "estimatedFairMarketValue" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "stateTax" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "occupationalTax" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "forestTaxable" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "bORValue" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "privateForestCropTax" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "managedForestLawTax" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "taxTotal" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "schoolCredit" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "lotteryCredit" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "firstDollarCredit" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "specialAssessmentDesc" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "specialAssessmentCharge" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "delinquentUtilityCharges" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "netTax" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "payment" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "amountDue" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "priorYearChargebacks" + sDelimeter;
            csvstring += "stateAssessedTelco" + sDelimeter;
            csv.WriteLine(csvstring);
            csvstring = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < results[0].items.Count; i++)
            {
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].recordNumber + sDelimeter;
                // Write Property Info
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].propertyInfo.localID1 + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].propertyInfo.localID2 + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].propertyInfo.legal + sDelimeter;
                foreach (string element in results[0].items[i].propertyInfo.zoning)
                {
                    csvstring += element;
                }
                csvstring += "\t";
                // Write Owner Info
                if (results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.mailingAddress == null)
                {
                    csvstring += "\t\t\t\t";
                }
                else
                {
                    csvstring += results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.mailingAddress.addressLine1 + sDelimeter;
                    csvstring += results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.mailingAddress.city + sDelimeter;
                    csvstring += results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.mailingAddress.state + sDelimeter;
                    csvstring += results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.mailingAddress.zipCode + sDelimeter;
                }
                for (int io = 0; io < results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.owners.Count; io++)
                {
                    csvstring += results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.owners[io].firstName + " ";
                    csvstring += results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.owners[io].lastName + " ";
                }
                csvstring += sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.owners[0].lastName + " " + results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.owners[0].firstName + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.owners[0].businessNameLine1 + sDelimeter;
                // Site Address
                if (results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.siteAddress == null)
                {
                    csvstring += "\t\t\t\t";
                }
                else
                {
                    csvstring += results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.siteAddress.addressLine1 + sDelimeter;
                    csvstring += results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.siteAddress.city + sDelimeter;
                    csvstring += results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.siteAddress.state + sDelimeter;
                    csvstring += results[0].items[i].ownerAndAddressInfo.siteAddress.zipCode + sDelimeter;
                }
                // Valuation Information
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].realProperty.classTotal.acres + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].realProperty.classTotal.landValue + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].realProperty.classTotal.improvementsValue + sDelimeter;
                // Tax Summary Information
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.landTaxableTotal + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.improvementsTaxableTotal + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.estimatedFairMarketValue + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.stateTax + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.occupationalTax + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.forestTaxable + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.bORValue + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.privateForestCropTax + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.managedForestLawTax + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.taxTotal + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.schoolCredit + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.lotteryCredit + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.firstDollarCredit + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.specialAssessmentDesc + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.specialAssessmentCharge + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.delinquentUtilityCharges + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.netTax + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.payment + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.amountDue + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.priorYearChargebacks + sDelimeter;
                csvstring += results[0].items[i].taxSummary.stateAssessedTelco + sDelimeter;
                csv.WriteLine(csvstring);
                csvstring = "";
                this.progressBar1.PerformStep();
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            csv.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Complete!", "Done Processing", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            this.progressBar1.Value = 0;
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error Alert",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: The last ToList() could be changed to FirstOrDefault() to remove array.  I wasn't sure if you need only one Municipality or more than one Municipality when I did the code.  The results[0] would then get the [0] removed.